# What is the meaning of 做一个梳理

Tags: meaning

I have the following text:

最好在创业之前对你所要做的事情做一个梳理，包括注册公司的流程、选址之类的事情。

What does 做一个梳理 mean?

I think it must be 'make a list'??

Answer (score 1):

梳理 has two basic ideas:

## Oxford

> VERB
>
> 1
>
> TEXTILES
>
> **card**
>
> 将羊毛梳理成毛线
>
> card wool into thread

> 2 整理 **comb**
>
> 梳理思路
>
> organize one's ideas

In line with the second meaning of comb -or- organize:

## KEY

> 2 {figurative} organize, analyze (data, etc.)

I think **organization** fits pretty well for your sentence here, especially because later in the sentence it mentions *流程* and *选址*.

So basically we have 做一个梳理 = Do some organization

Answer (score 1):

You can understand it as making a list.

梳理 as a verb in this setting means "organising ideas" (Oxford EN-CN). Apparently making a list is one way to do that. Since "organising ideas" might sound awkward in the sentence in English, it's perfectly okay to say "make a plan", "make a list", "prioritise", "think it though" or "tease out" etc.

Besides "make a list", I think "sort out" would sound quite alright here as well:

> 最好在创业之前对你所要做的事情做一个梳理，包括注册公司的流程、选址之类的事情。
>
> Before starting your own company, you'd better sort out what you need to do first, including stuff like registration procedures, location and so on.

Answer (score 0):

"make a list", yes.

梳理 is a compound word of two verbs, 梳 and 理, which just repeat each other. They both are actions of combing hair or cut hair.

梳理 is used for a more abstract meaning that include:

To keep things neat and tidy

To sort things out

To arrange in a certain way

To make a to do list

To prioritize tasks

To make it organized